# Substituir letra por vazio ou em branco, algo do tipo Replace("letras","")

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, .net, string

Existe no banco de dados um campo `A1_ZTEL` ele é `varchar(15)`. Dessa forma cada usuário inseriu registro de todas as formas, com barra, ponto, virgula e letra.

Agora preciso montar um *form* e ler esse campo de outra tabela que é `varchar(40)` e salvar no `A1_ZTEL` (`varchar 15`).

Antes eu mostro no FORM, pegando apenas os 15 primeiros dígito e no formato `(99)9999-9999?9` (fone ou cel). Até aqui, tudo certo.

Para isso, trato o retorno do banco, e o faço com `Replace()` e `Trim()`

Exemplo:

```
  p.ZC_CELULAR = reader["A1_ZTEL"].ToString().Trim().Substring(0,15).Replace("-","").Replace(".","").Replace(",","").Replace("/","")
```

Desta forma eu posso pegar somente os numero e colocar no `input` com a máscara.
Agora me deparei com letras, como eu faço pra substituir letras por nada? Algo como: `Replace("letras","")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode pegar apenas os números e não precisar fazer os demais `Replace`:

```
p.ZC_CELULAR  = Regex.Replace(reader["A1_ZTEL"].ToString(), "[^0-9]", "");
```

Ou:

```
p.ZC_CELULAR = Regex.Match(reader["A1_ZTEL"].ToString(), @"\d+").Value;
```

[Exemplo aqui](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/04/remove-non-digits-or-non-letters-from-a-string-in-c/)

Comment: Obrigada, muito show... funcionou perfeito!

Comment: Recomendo que salve apenas números no banco de dados OU monte seu form para tratar esses dados, uma possibilidade é usar uma máscara no input para que ele faça automaticamente o pattern de telefone: `(xx) 99999-9999`

Comment: Se quiser/gostar de jquery, recomendo esse recurso: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Pelo que vi deve ser Totvs , no Configurador você define a mascara no campo.

Comment: Sim, @DavidDias , estou tratando no front  a entrada de dados, colocando uma mascará da biblioteca Jquery (99)9999-9999?9. O problema em si, não era o salvar, pois o salvar vai apenas numero por causa da máscara. O carregar os dados (o Editar), que vindo do banco poderia vir com caracteres que não fosse numero.

Comment: @Motta , não usamos Totvs .

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres , beleza é que Totvs usa campos com estes nome A!_Z....

Answer (score 8):

Eu faria assim porque é muito mais performático

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("123.456.789/ 0001-99X".Strip());
        WriteLine("(19)9-98/754?283 A".Strip());
    }
}

public static class StringExt {
    public static string Strip(this string str) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        foreach (var chr in str) if (char.IsDigit(chr)) sb.Append(chr);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/x6pd4c). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jE5NT5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/StripDigit.cs).

Comment: obrigada @Maniero. vc como sempre ajudando.